# Tikz grid does not use tikzpicture unit lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to Tikz. Please, consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \fill (1,1) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw[very thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \fill (1,1) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem I have is that in the second picture, the grid is not taking into account the unit lengths. What am I missing? What should I do to let the grid "know" that I've changed the units?

[image: PDFLaTeX result]

Comment: What is it, that you want to achieve? Do you want to have a 4x4 grid getting displayed in the second example?

Comment: @TobiBS: I want to obtain a similar picture to the first one (in this case, a 4-by-4 grid). I do not want to use the `scale` option, since that would change the size of the circle, too. The problem is that I don't understand why the grid doesn't change.

Comment: then I got you right and provided an answer, it is `step` is initialized with `1cm` and hence does not change with `x` or `y` unit modifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [pgfmanual](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), the grid is drawn with steps as configured through `/tikz/step=h` which as far as the manual says is `a number or dimension or coordinate` and has `(no default, initially 1cm)`.

So if you want the grid to be not drawn with 1cm, you have to change the `step`, as in (or locally, just for the grid drawing command):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \fill (1,1) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,step=0.5cm]
    \draw[very thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \fill (1,1) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Going through the PGF/Tikz manual, I've seen that it is also possible to set the `step` option without dimension. By setting `step=1`, any change in the size of the x or y units will automatically be reflected to the grid (meaning that there is no need to change the `step`). I wonder why is this not the default and must be specified each time the unit lengths are changed.

Comment: Good question, @digital-Ink but maybe start of a new question?

Answer (score 4):

Grid separation is controlled by `xstep` and `ystep` which store the value in `\tikz@grid@x` and `\tikz@grid@y` respectively. Their initial value are defined in `tikz.code.tex`

```
\def\tikz@grid@x{1cm}%
\def\tikz@grid@y{1cm}%
```

In your second example, you set `x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm`, which means `(-2, -2)` is parsed as `(-1cm, -1cm)` and `(2, 2)` is parsed as `(1cm, 1cm)`. This is because when coordinates is passed to parse, they are first checked if the x and y coordinate is with unit by `\tikz@checkunit`. Then tikz can judge if it is with a unit by `\iftikz@isdimension`, if not the coordinate is set by `\pgfpointxy`, otherwise the coordinate is set by `\pgfpoint`. Actually there are four cases to handle, related code is

```
\def\tikz@@@parse@regular#1#2#3){%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#3}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tikz@parse@splitxyz{#1}{#2}#3,%
  \else%
    \tikz@checkunit{#2}%
    \iftikz@isdimension%
      \tikz@checkunit{#3}%
      \iftikz@isdimension%
        \def\pgfutil@next{#1{\pgfpoint{#2}{#3}}}%
      \else%
        \def\pgfutil@next{#1{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{#2}{0pt}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{#3}}}}%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \tikz@checkunit{#3}%
      \iftikz@isdimension%
        \def\pgfutil@next{#1{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{0pt}{#3}}{\pgfpointxy{#2}{0}}}}%
      \else%
        \def\pgfutil@next{#1{\pgfpointxy{#2}{#3}}}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \pgfutil@next%
}%
```

Similar parse mechanism is also applied to `xstep` and `ystep`

```
    \tikz@checkunit{\tikz@grid@x}%
    \iftikz@isdimension%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpoint{\tikz@grid@x}{0pt}}%
    \else%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointxy{\tikz@grid@x}{0}}%
    \fi%
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    \tikz@checkunit{\tikz@grid@y}%
    \iftikz@isdimension%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\tikz@grid@y}}%
    \else%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointxy{0}{\tikz@grid@y}}%
    \fi%
    \advance\pgf@xb by\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@yb by\pgf@y%
    \pgfpathgrid[stepx=\pgf@xb,stepy=\pgf@yb]%
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\tikz@lasty}}%
```

In your example they are just `1cm`, so the same fig can be draw by

```
\draw (-1cm, -1cm) grid (1cm, 1cm);
```

and `\fill (1, 1) circle [radius=3pt];` is equal to `\fill (0.5cm, 0.5cm) circle (3pt);` which is not on any grid point.