# Invisible edge and boundary: How can I generate full A4 perfect grids and "full vertical" lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

### Introduction

I want to generate a perfect and full controllable grid of dots or simple grids. But LaTeX isn't allowing a whole grid, it seems there exists an "invisible boundary" at the top of the page. A boundary that lines cannot cross and grids cannot pass. I will explain better.

My code is this one here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%%%%%%%{BASE PACKAGES}%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={0mm,0mm},vmargin={0mm,0mm}]{geometry}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%{BASE PACKAGES}%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%{COLORS}%%%%%%%
\definecolor{5}{RGB}{198, 67, 67}
%%%%%%%{COLORS}%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%{ROUNDED LINES}%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,scopes}
%%%%%%%{ROUNDED LINES}%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]   

\draw[gray!60] (0,0) grid (100,100);

\draw[5, line width=0.15cm] (2.600,0) -- (2.600,100);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But if you take a look closely, you will note some annoying things (Figure 1):

- The grid pattern stops at the top, I mean it doesn't "fill" the whole A4 paper
- The red line stop at the top rendering the same problem.

> Figure 1
>
> [image]

If I change the value of the line to 101, like:

```
\draw[5, line width=0.15cm] (2.600,0) -- (2.600,101);
```

The whole thing is destroyed and, even so, the "top gap"/"invisible boundary" persists (Figure 2):

> Figure 2:
>
> [image]

### My Question

I want to generate a perfect, and full controllable grid of dots or simple grids. More precisely, **how can I put a straight line, from top to bottom, without the "gap" (Figure 3) and how can I generate a grid that fills the whole A4 paper?**

> Figure 3:
>
> [image]

Comment: [noheadfoot] might help, but the header should have left an even bigger gap.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `grid` from `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorgrid, gridunit=mm, texcoord]{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\null\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to use `[remember picture,overlay]` and the special `current page` node. Leaving only necessary code, this would be the idea:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%{COLORS}%%%%%%%
\definecolor{5}{RGB}{198, 67, 67}
%%%%%%%{COLORS}%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    
    \draw[gray!60] (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east);
    
    \draw[5, line width=0.15cm] (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in a grid on the whole page and a line going from top to bottom, as you can see below. However you need to compile twice for this to work!

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But, is there some way to render small squares in the grid?

Comment: Set ```step=0.5cm``` for the drawing of the grid, as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553668/tikz-grid-does-not-use-tikzpicture-unit-lengths